# jsf primefaces fileupload on submit

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, primefaces

Does anyone know how I can upload multiple files with primefaces (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) when I click my own submit button? The upload-button there should not be visible, because I want to chose the upload-time on my own.

I have multiple pm-fileupload components in my document, so I want to upload them all together.

is there a way? Or must I use the old browser-upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">` generated by a `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>`.

The `<p:fileUpload mode="advanced">` indeed isn't suitable for this requirement, or you must turn on automatic immediate upload on select by adding `auto="true"`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is primeface for my question the right thing or is there another better solution? how can I achieve that all files are uploaded when i click one submit button in the form?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "better", so I'll ignore that part which only asks for non-constructive opinions. Try a discussion forum instead. As to how you could achieve the requirement anyway, I've already answered that. I've even proposed 2 potential solutions. Did you read it?

Comment: @BalusC: Can mode `simple` use parameter `fileUploadListener`? Or should `value`?